# Central Limit Theorem different versions

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference

Which one is correct about the *Central Limit Theorem*:

1. If $X_{1}, ... , X_{n}$ are i.i.d continuous random variables with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then as $n \rightarrow \infty$,
   $$ \sqrt{n} \frac{\bar{X} - \mu}{\sigma} $$ will have the *standard normal distribution*

or

2. If $X_{1}, ... , X_{n}$ are i.i.d continuous random variables with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then as $n \rightarrow \infty$,
   $$ \sqrt{n} \frac{\bar{X} - \mu}{\sigma} $$ will have *normal distribution* $N(0, \sigma^2)$

According to a book: "Introduction to Mathematical Statistics", by Hogg and Craig, the first one is true. But I also see from other sources that the second one is true.

Thanks.

Comment: Work out the variance.

Comment: @J.G. but it should be just one version that is true..

Comment: Both versions are incorrect (for example, if the distribution of every $X_i$ is discrete, then **none** of the random variables $\sqrt n(\bar X_n-\mu)/\sigma$ is normally distributed).

Comment: The above statement is itself incorrect. The conditions of this version of CLT is simply that $\mathrm{var}(X)<\infty$. CLT claims nothing about finite $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n-\mu)/\sigma$ (you need the Berry-Esseen theorem for that), it simply says this sequence converges in distribution to a normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X_i$ are iid, we know that
$$\mathrm{var}\left(\sqrt{n}\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sigma}\right)=\frac{n}{\sigma^2}\mathrm{var}\left(\bar{X}-\mu\right)=\frac{n}{\sigma^2}\mathrm{var}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)=\frac{n}{\sigma^2}\frac{1}{n^2}(n\sigma^2)=1$$
so the limit is a standard normal.

Version 1 is correct, version 2 is wrong.